# replace @ operator in python2?

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to learn python, and came over the @ operator.
the @ infix operator that is designated to be used for matrix multiplication in python 3.
But im using python 2.

```
def spaceship_cockpit_coordinates(self):
"""Calculates and returns the position of the 'cockpit' when
the spaceship rotates"""
rot_mat = np.array([[np.cos(self.angle), -1*np.sin(self.angle)],
[np.sin(self.angle), np.cos(self.angle)]])
pos = np.array([(self.width/2), 0])
rot = pos@rot_mat
cent = [self.x + self.width/2, self.y + self.height/2]
  
return (np.array(cent) + rot).tolist()
```

how can the rot = pos@rot_mat be replaced so it works in python 2?

Comment: If you are tryin to learn Python, you should use Python 3. Anyway, you can use `np.dot`

Comment: Why are you learning python 2? It's deprecated since over a year back and should not be used. You should switch to Python 3

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

Comment: `np.einsum` or, depending on the array dimensions `np.dot`.  What `numpy` version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try matrix multiplication in Numpy itself.
For matrix multiplication, you can use

```
np.matmul(pos,rot_mat)
```

Comment: what is matmul?

Comment: matrix multiplication https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html